# Does Hyper-V Server R2 have VPN client?

Tags: vpn, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Does Hyper-V Server R2 have VPN client?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the standalone [Hyper-v server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/default.aspx) product, that just does hyper-v then this is just providing the Hyper-v service, there is no VPN client. If you are talking about Server 2008 with Hyper-v installed, this does have the VPN client in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'does Windows Server 2008 (with Hyper-V) R2 have a VPN client?' or do you mean 'does Windows Server 2008 R2 have a VPN client inside the hypervisor service?'

If the former then yes but only certain protocols. If the latter then no as that would be a very weird thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough I run it as my desktop OS(gotta love our unlimited licenses with MS) and I just took a look. On Server 2008 R2 I do not have a standard windows VPN client while Hyper-V is installed(I cannot speak for it when the Hyper-V role is not installed).

I do however have OpenVPN installed and it's virtual network adapter shows up fine on my system.